# How I show that this sequence does not have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

The sequence is given as follows: x_1=0 and x_{n+1} = 1-2x_n

I know that every even term the sequence gives positive integer and every odd term it gives negative integer. My idea was to show that the subsequence x_k = x_2n and the subsequence of every odd term diverges. Does it have any validity and how should I start with it. Should I try proof by contradiction?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Comment: I reverted the last edit since it was obscuring the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Prove that $x_{2n+1}\leq -n$ for all $n\geq 2$ and $x_{2n}\geq n$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You get the *explicit* form for the sequence, using the standard method for solving such a linear recurrence: the fixed point $a$ of the equation ($a=1-2a$) being $a=1/3$, the "change of sequence" $y_n=x_n-1/3$ leads to a simpler recurrence: $y_{n+1}=-2y_n$, from which you easily deduce
$$x_n=\frac13+\frac{(-2)^n}6,$$
which has no convergent subsequence since $|x_n|\to+\infty$.

Alternatively (less explicitely), you may look for some constants $\alpha>0$ and $\beta$ such that for some $N$,
$$\forall n\ge N\quad(-1)^nx_n\ge2^n\alpha+\beta$$
(I found $\beta=1$ for the heredity, and then $N=4,\alpha=\frac18$ for the initialization).